# I can not set the image when page load occurs with the virtual path and image is already in the root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can not set the image when page load occurs with the virtual path and image is already in the root folder.

Following is the both file

Default2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default2.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/abc.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx):

```
Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/abc.jpg");
```

Comment: can i try this:

    `Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl(Server.MapPath("~/MyImages/abc.jpg").ToString());`

Comment: `Server.MapPath` returns the operating system path (e.g. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\myimages\abc.jpg`) -- that's not what you want here.